# Define Function -- why is this code wrong?

Tags: python, function

This code is wrong; the correct version is posted below, but I don't understand the reasoning behind why this doesn't work. It seems logically structured.

```
def absolute_value(x): #define a function "absolute_value"
    """returns the absolute value of x.
    """
    if x < 0:
        return x = -x
    else:
        return x
```

This is the right code:

```
def absolute_value(x): #define a function "absolute_value"
    """returns the absolute value of x.
    """
    if x < 0:
        x = -x
    return x
```

Comment: You can’t return *and* assign in the same statement.

Comment: Because assignment is a *statement*, you can only return *values*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that looks like your first attempt:

```
def absolute_value(x): #define a function "absolute_value"
    """returns the absolute value of x.
    """
    if x < 0:
        return -x
    else:
        return x
```

However, it avoids the assignment which is not an expression.

Here's an alternative approach using indexed tuple to create ternary expression:

```
def absolute_value(x):
   return (x , -x ) [x <  0]
```

One last thing to note:  Your code implies that you might believe the way to pass the value back to calling program is to modify the argument `x`.  However, the value of `x` doesn't modify the parameter used in the call to absolute_value().  Consider this code calling your second function:

```
>>> x = -3
>>> print absolute_value(x)
3
>>> print x
-3
```

As you can see `x` still has the value it had prior to the invocation.  The value is passed back to calling function as a return value.  So, this is how you would need to call the function to alter x:

```
>>> print x ; x=absolute_value(x)
-3
>>> print x
3
```

That is, you would need to explicitly assign the return value to `x`.

Answer (score -1):

In python 'return' cannot take a statement.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html

I hope this would help.